# how to make asp.net hyperlink to stop encoding the urls?

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, urlencode

I have got a `BulletedList` with `DisplayMode="HyperLink"`.

```
<asp:BulletedList runat="server" DisplayMode="HyperLink" ID="LevelsList"></asp:BulletedList>
```

I add items to the list with this code:
    LevelsList.Items.Add(new ListItem(curSubPage.PageName, curSubPage.shortURL));

The URL links contain Hebrew strings and they get encoded:

The markup the the asp.net generates is something like that:

```
<a href="%d7%91%d7%a0%d7%99%d7%99%d7%aa_%d7%90%d7%a4%d7%9c%d7%99%d7%a7%d7%a6%d7%99%d7%95%d7%aa_%d7%90%d7%99%d7%a0%d7%98%d7%a8%d7%a0%d7%98%d7%99%d7%95%d7%aa">בניית אפליקציות אינטרנטיות</a>
```

While the right markup should be:

```
<a href="בניית_אפליקציות_אינטרנטיות">בניית אפליקציות אינטרנטיות</a>
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Google seems to see those 2 URLs as different pages and that means double content..

Comment: Maybe you can check the culture-info of you asp.net program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From quick investigation, looks like ASP.NET is encoding it in its "low level" code, so no direct solution.

You can simply write your own Bulleted List using custom Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptLevelsList" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate><ul></HeaderTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li><a href="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Value") %>"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Text") %></a></li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And to bind it in code behind:

```
List<ListItem> links = new List<ListItem>();
links.Add(new ListItem("my page", "Somepage.aspx"));
links.Add(new ListItem("משהו בעברית", "http://www.כתובת_כלשהי_כאן.com"));
rptLevelsList.DataSource = links;
rptLevelsList.DataBind();
```

Note that from what I've seen, IE8 still does not support non english URL address - the above link is not clickable in that browser, while Chrome let you click it, but encode the URL to something else as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Those links are clickable in IE7 and 8 when they are not encoded as well