# Opening a new smaller window when clicking on link

Tags: asp.net

I have a link that works fine when I click on it

```
<a href="https://websitename.org/form/formname.aspx?sessionid=<%= txtsession.value %>" > Add user</a>
```

I would like to resize the new window so I tried this

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:window.open('https://websitename.org/form/formname.aspx?sessionid=<%= txtsession.value %>','','left=250px, top=245px, width=700px, height=450px, scrollbars=no, status=no, resizable=no');return false;">add user</asp:LinkButton>
```

Which does open a new smaller window but when I opem link url shows like this

```
https://websitename.org/form/formname.aspx?sessionid=%3C%=%20txtsession.value%20%%3E
```

when it should be like this

```
https://websitename.org/form/formname.aspx?sessionid=abc-123jkl (assuming txtsession.value = abc-123jkl  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the `LinkButton` for your work and use a `Literal` - render there your code that open the window. The reason is that the `LinkButton` is encode that parameter and you have no control to that unless you make a filter - from the other hand you have full control on a literal render... for example you can do:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="txtRenderOnme" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Literal>
```

and on code behind

```
txtRenderOnme.Text = "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"javascript:window.open('https://websitename.org/form/formname.aspx?sessionid=" + txtsession.value + "','','left=250px, top=245px, width=700px, height=450px, scrollbars=no, status=no, resizable=no');return false;\">add user</a>";
```

and there you go, you have the result you ask for.

You can also take a look at : [how to make asp.net hyperlink to stop encoding the urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237361/how-to-make-asp-net-hyperlink-to-stop-encoding-the-urls)

Comment: im getting a 'End of statement expected' error on the code behind, cant find syntax error

Comment: @anatp_123 I have update it, test it on me and works. At any case just see what is the error - I can not debug your code there...

Comment: when you say behind code , you mean <% %> tags right? sorry im very new to asp.net first time for me

Comment: @anatp_123 No, code behind is on the file that ends with `.cs` or inside the same code at the first... is the code that runs on server. I am not use `<% %>`

Comment: i see that has to be why its not working, i dont have a cs file, going to do my research , thanks